# how to get current wallpaper information in android?

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

I want to retrieve info about current Wallpaper like its name, path, etc. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

I am currently calling `WallpaperManager` in service at some part of my code.

Does android provide any inbuilt function or method for this?

Answer (score 1):

H i would like to share the code to get the Current Wallpaper Drawable Image as follows :

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

And If Your current Wallpaper is Of the Live Wallpaper than You were able to get the Information by simple code as :

```
wallpaperManager.getWallpaperInfo();
```

which returns the Object of WallPaperInfo Class and You are able to retrived the data.

Comment: its all we know but i want to retrieve its name, path etc. plz read que. again.

Comment: @Rajan can we use this wallpaper again?